# Oracle stored delete procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

```
CREATE TABLE kategorijos(
kat_id number(11) not null,
kat_pavadinimas varchar(255),
CONSTRAINT kategorijos_pk PRIMARY KEY(kat_id)
);

create or replace procedure delete_kategorijos (kat_id number)
is
begin
delete from kategorijos where kat_id = kat_id;
end;
```

I call procedure:

```
BEGIN
delete_kategorijos(1);
END;
```

This procedure delete ALL records in database, but it really must delete only row where kat_id = 1 , what is wrong in my procedure ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the below line of code for deleting records

```
   delete from kategorijos where kat_id = kat_id;
```

Where in condition filed you can find that

```
    where kat_id = kat_id;
```

Which is always true cause you are comparing same value thats why its deleting all the records

Answer (score 1):

It is better to give the parameter another name, as follows:

create or replace procedure delete_kategorijos (l_kat_id number)
is
begin
delete from kategorijos where kat_id = l_kat_id;
end;

But think about the following:
- what if kat_id = 1 does not exist?
- what if the record is locked by another transaction?

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to always use aliases.

```
create or replace procedure delete_kategorijos (kat_id number)
is
begin
  delete from kategorijos k where k.kat_id = delete_kategorijos.kat_id;
end;
```